# Extract field from xml file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, xmllint

**xml file:**

```
<head>
  <head2>
    <dict type="abc" file="/path/to/file1"></dict>
    <dict type="xyz" file="/path/to/file2"></dict>
  </head2>
</head>
```

I need to extract the list of files from this. So the output would be

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
```

So far, I've managed to the following.

```
grep "<dict*file=" /path/to/xml.file | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F= '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Can you use `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`? `awk/sed/grep` are not the right tools for processing xml

Comment: `xmllint` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty based on your sample, not xml possibilties

```
# sed a bit secure
sed -e '/<head>/,/<\/head>/!d' -e '/.*[[:blank:]]file="\([^"]*\)".*/!d' -e 's//\1/' YourFile

# sed in brute force
sed -n 's/.*[[:blank:]]file="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' -e 's//\1/' YourFile



# awk quick unsecure using your sample
awk -F 'file="|">' '/<head>/{h=1} /\/head>{h=0} h && /[[:blank:]]file/ { print $2 }' YourFile
```

now, i don't promote this kind of extraction on XML unless your really know how is your source in format and content (extra field, escaped quote, content of string like tag format, ...) are a big cause of failure and unexpected result and no more appropriate tools are available

now to use your own script

```
#grep "<dict*file=" /path/to/xml.file | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F= '{print $NF}'
awk '! /<dict.*file=/ {next} {$0=$3;FS="\"";$0=$0;print $2;FS=OFS}' YourFile
```

- no need of a grep with awk, use starting pattern filter `/<dict.*file/`
- second awk for using a different separator (FS) could be done inside the same script changing FS but because it only occur at next evaluation (next line by default), you could force a reevaluation of current content with $0=$0 in this case

Answer (score 1):

Use an `xmllint` solution with `-xpath` as `//head/head2/dict/@file`

```
xmllint --xpath "//head/head2/dict/@file" input-xml | awk 'BEGIN{FS="file="}{printf "%s\n%s\n", gensub(/"/,"","g",$2), gensub(/"/,"","g",$3)}'
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
```

Unfortunately couldn't provide a pure `xmllint` logic, because thought applying,

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//head/head2/dict/@file)" input-xml
```

will return the `file` attributes from both the nodes, but it was returning only the first instance.

So added coupled my logic with `GNU Awk`, to extract the required values, doing

```
xmllint --xpath "//head/head2/dict/@file" input-xml
```

returns values as

```
file="/path/to/file1" file="/path/to/file2"
```

On the above output, setting a string de-limiter as `file=` and removing the double-quotes using `gensub()` function solved the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Also PE [**p**erl **e**verywhere :) ] solution:

```
perl -MXML::LibXML -E 'say $_->to_literal for XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>q{file.xml})->findnodes(q{/head/head2/dict/@file})'
```

it prints

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
```

For the above you need to have installed the [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) module.

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet` it would be:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//head/head2/dict/@file" -nl input.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

This command:

```
awk -F'[=" ">]' '{print $12}' file
```

Will produces:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
```